# JsonParseExeption failed to deserialized object

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I'm receiving object from a BackEnd that looks like this :

```
{name : String,
 author : String,
 updater : String,
 media : String,
}
```

But sometimes media is equal to somethings else, but i can't change the service but i would like to leave it alone.

```
 -media :[{type:String,
           path:String}
         {type:String
          path:String}]
```

If this type is not a string , as showed, just put null instead.

I'm using Gson to decode my json string.

Edit : 
Part of my class :

```
private String id;
private String nom;
private String nom_en;
private String adresse;
private String adresse2;
private String cp;
private String ville;
private String pays;
private String coordonnees_x;
private String coordonnees_y;
private String contactName;
private String email;
private String telephone_1;
private String telephone_2;
private String fax;
private String website;
private String date_ajout;
private String ArticleRefId;
private String media;
private int type;
private List<AdresseCategorie> categories;
private String ArticleTitle;
private ArticleObject article;
```

Comment: post the code of your class you are deserializing this into

Answer (score 1):

There a few of available options, the simplest one is to change `media` field to `Object`.

Doing so, Gson will create a `String` if your JSON is like the first case, an array of `Map`s in the second case. The map will contain two keys, `type` and `path`. With an `instanceof` you can check `media` field and do whatever your need.